# ""org.dspace.core.Context.getDBConnection()" is null" error when trying to install DSpace

Tags: database, postgresql, pgadmin-4, dspace

I attempted to install DSpace on Windows 10 for the first time. I followed [this online tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-lmBHp6pDE).

I installed the following dependencies:

apache-maven-3.9.6-bin
apache-ant-1.10.14-bin
jdk-21_windows-x64_bin
postgresql-16.1-1-windows-x64
DSpace-dspace-7.6.1
apache-tomcat-9.0.85
SQL2022-SSEI-Dev

It's not the exact same dependencies as in the tutorial (which may be the issue). It was going smoothly until it came time to create an administrator whereupon I got this message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKisc.png)

I have tried googling this issue but no one else seems to have faced similar problems.

DB Connection returns null seems to imply it's a problem with connecting to DB and authenticating. So I opened SQLShell (psql) to test the connection and DB connection is fine. I suspect it's a missing file or package. But even then not sure where to start. Some files like xmlui or jspui seems to be missing from the version of DSpace files I downloaded. Could that be the cause? If so how/where do I get those files?